# Getting error for KeyguardManager system service while developing finger print using ionic cordova and running on android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, fingerprint

```
error: cannot find symbol
                .getSystemService(this, KeyguardManager.class);
                ^
  symbol:   method getSystemService(BiometricActivity,Class<KeyguardManager>)
  location: class ContextCompat
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`.

  ```
  Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
  ```
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
  full insights.
- Get more [help at](https://help.gradle.org)

BUILD FAILED in 5s

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
E:\IONIC\Walkin\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
E:\IONIC\Walkin\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\de\niklasmerz\cordova\biometric\BiometricActivity.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
                .getSystemService(this, KeyguardManager.class);
                ^
  symbol:   method getSystemService(BiometricActivity,Class<KeyguardManager>)
  location: class ContextCompat
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
  full insights.
- Get more [help at](https://help.gradle.org)

BUILD FAILED in 5s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android --device exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```